# Syntax to check more than one condition on exclusive gateway using kiefunctions

Tags: conditional-statements, jbpm

I am trying to check more than one conditions to redirect the flow on an exclusive gateway using kiefunctions JavaScript in jbpm. I am using the below syntax but I think I might be using the wrong syntax

```
return Kiefunctions.isTrue(customer.isValid) && customer.status == “retired” || customer.status == “employed”;
```

Can someone suggest me the correct syntax please

Answer (score 1):

Probably KieFunctions is not written correctly (case-sensitive)

Try this and share the result:

```
return  KieFunctions.isTrue(customer.isValid) && (KieFunctions.equalsTo(customer.status, "retired") || KieFunctions.equalsTo(customer.status, "employed"));
```